# Database SQL Query Issue Error #1066

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Query Issue:

```
SELECT B.branchNo, B.city, S.staffNo, fName, lName, propertyNo
FROM Branch B, Staff S, PropertyForRent P
WHERE B.branchNo = S.branchNo AND S.staffNo = P.staffNo
ORDER BY B.branchNo, S.staffNo, propertyNo ;
```

Error #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'B'

I used similar queries to this and they work, this one just doesn't.

I also tried:

```
SELECT B.branchNo, B.city, S.staffNo, S.fName, S.lName, S.propertyNo
FROM Branch B, Staff S, PropertyForRent P
WHERE B.branchNo = S.branchNo AND S.staffNo = P.staffNo
ORDER BY B.branchNo, S.staffNo, propertyNo ;
```

All Help Appreciated :)

Comment: I don't understand why are you using Aliases in the first place? just use the full table name and be rid of it

Comment: Aliases are needed because there are columns with the same column names.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it should work or maybe I am missing something but its strange. Try this:

```
SELECT B.branchNo, B.city, S.staffNo, fName, lName, propertyNo
FROM Branch B 
JOIN Staff S 
ON B.branchNo = S.branchNo 
JOIN PropertyForRent P
ON S.staffNo = P.staffNo
ORDER BY B.branchNo, S.staffNo, propertyNo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT B.branchNo, 
       B.city, 
       S.staffNo, 
       S.fName, 
       S.lName, 
       S.propertyNo

FROM Branch B
Join Staff S
On   B.branchNo = S.branchNo

Join PropertyForRent P
On   S.staffNo = P.staffNo

ORDER BY B.branchNo, S.staffNo, S.propertyNo ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting an "S.propertyNo" in your `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT B.branchNo, B.city, S.staffNo, S.fName, S.lName, S.propertyNo
FROM Branch B, Staff S, PropertyForRent P
WHERE B.branchNo = S.branchNo AND S.staffNo = P.staffNo
ORDER BY B.branchNo, S.staffNo, S.propertyNo ;
```